# How to send SysRq command over ssh connection?

Tags: ssh, linux-kernel, embedded, magic-sysrq

I am working on BeagleboneBlack based custom board,
Recently I was debugging system hang issues, I had access to debug console using `minicom`, And I could enable log using key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, F `.

However all production devices won't have debug console. I won't be able to connect it to through `minicom`, However I will get access through ssh connection.

Now, I wanted to know if there is any way to send SysRq keys over ssh connection,

In normal working of device, if I use `echo h > /proc/sysrq-trigger` output is printed on the debug(or serial) console(minicom) and not on ssh.:( ,
**is there any way to get this output to ssh terminal ?**

I know what I am asking is somewhat like impossible as, if system locks-up ssh connection won't be alive. **But just in case if connection is alive then I want to know if there is any way to send SysRq keys.**

Comment: `SysRq` is actually a hardware interrupt.  No local keyboard -> no `SysRq`.

Comment: I was under impression that if you can send `break` somehow, it would be possible to trigger SysRq.

Comment: `break` has to do with the current line discipline.  `SysRq`, like I said, is a hardware interrupt.  Now, whether it's possible to send a control sequence over a serial line that has the same _effect_ as `SysRq`, I don't know (I'm not that familiar with Linux).

Answer (score 3):

You can't directly get the response to be shown to the ssh terminal, but the kernel's output is recorded in `dmesg` (and usually `/var/log/messages` too); so you can `echo h > /proc/sysrq-trigger; dmesg | tail` to see what was printed.

Answer (score 3):

The SysRq direct function only works on the console.

On a standard "VGA" console this is the literal key SysRq (sometimes marked Print Screen) in conjunction with Alt and "command".

On a serial console this can be accessed via the BREAK signal.

However, over SSH there is no direct access to SysRq and you have to use the `/proc/sysrq-trigger` file instead.

The kernel documentation goes into more detail on SysRq and how different key combinations work on different platforms: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysrq.txt

Since SysRq output is generated by the kernel it goes into the ring buffer.  This can be read by `dmesg`.

Also, depending on how you have set up your OS, `syslog` or `rsyslog` can direct kernel output to a file
eg for `rsyslog`

```
$ModLoad imklog
kern.*    -/var/log/kernel
```

`systemd` based systems can expose this log via the `journalctl` command.